# Representations of Spin(2n)

Tags: representation-theory

Consider $G=Spin(2n)$. It is known that its representation ring is 
\begin{eqnarray}
R(G)\cong\mathbb{Z}[V, \bigwedge\nolimits^2 V, \cdots, \bigwedge\nolimits^{n-2}V, S^+, S^-]
\end{eqnarray}
where $V$ is the standard representation. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the weights $L_1+\cdots+L_n$ and $L_1+\cdots+L_{n-1}-L_n$ respectively, and $V_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$ be irreducible representations with highest weights $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. I have two questions:

1.How can we express $\bigwedge\nolimits^k V_\alpha$ and $\bigwedge\nolimits^k V_\beta$ as polynomials of the generators of $R(G)$ as above?

2. I know that 
   \begin{eqnarray}
   S^+\otimes S^+\cong\bigoplus_{p\geq 1}\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-2p}V\oplus V_\alpha
   \end{eqnarray}
   Is it true that
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \bigwedge\nolimits^2S^+\cong\bigoplus_{k\geq 0}\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-(4k+2)}V ?
   \end{eqnarray}